# Integral solutions to $1\times2+2\times3+\cdots+m\times(m+1)=n\times(n+1)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I just stumbled across the identity
$$1\times2+2\times3+\cdots+34\times35=119\times120,$$
which made me wonder about integral solutions to
$$\sum_{k=1}^mk\times(k+1)=n\times(n+1).$$
The left hand side can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{k=1}^mk^2+\sum_{k=1}^mk=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{3},$$
which shows that the original problem is equivalent to solving
$$m(m+1)(m+2)=3n(n+1),$$
over the integers. This looks nicer already, but I'm still unable to determine its integral solutions. The latter equation also defines an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}$, which might help me if I knew how to use Sage or Magma or the likes. Checking some small values of $(m,n)$ shows that the pairs
$$(3,4),\qquad(8,15),\qquad(20,55),\qquad(34,119),$$
are solutions, for what it's worth.

Comment: um it's pretty clearly defined over $\Bbb Q$

Comment: [This page (see (5) ~ (10))](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TetrahedralNumber.html) says that there are only five solutions with $(1,1)$.

Comment: @mathlove: When I saw $119,120$ what first came to mind was $119^2+120^2 = 169^2$ and the associated Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$. Then a search with OEIS turned a hit.

Comment: I just made a [new post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052632/on-11921202-1692-and-p-239) about $119^2+120^2=169^2$.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

OEIS is our friend. The sequence $n=1,4,15,55,119$ is [A102349](https://oeis.org/A102349) and, being *integer* points on the elliptic curve,
$$F(m,n)=\frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{6} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ 
should be finite. The $n$ are solutions to numbers that both triangular and tetrahedral ([A027568](https://oeis.org/A027568)), with the largest as,
$$F(34,\,119) = 7140$$

---

$\color{green}{Update}$: In fact, in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052632/on-11921202-134-and-p-239) we have,

$$\frac{u(u+1)(u+2)(u+3)}{8} = \frac{v(v+1)(v+2)}{6} = \frac{w(w+1)}{2} =7140$$

with $u=2\times\color{blue}7,\;v=2\times\color{blue}{17},$ and $w= \color{blue}{7\times17} =119\,$. So $7140$ is also $3\times$ the [pentatope number](https://oeis.org/A027568) $2380$.