# On $119^2+120^2=13^4\,$ and $p=239$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, big-list, pythagorean-triples, pell-type-equations

We are familiar with, $$\frac\pi4=4\arctan\tfrac15-\arctan\tfrac1{239}$$Let $p=a+b=239$ and $(a,b,c,d)=(120,119,13,2).\,$ Some years back, I observed this rather *long* list of Diophantine relations and *Pell equations* that they satisfied,
$$120^2-119^2 = 239$$
$$120^2 + 119^2 = 13^4$$
$$239^2+(13^4-1)^2=13^8$$
$$239^2 - 2\cdot13^4 = -1$$
$$13^4 - \frac{119\times120}2\,2^2 = 1$$
$$1^3+3^3+5^3+\dots+(2\cdot13^2-1)^3 = (13^2\cdot239)^2$$
$$1^3+2^3+3^3 +\dots+(239^2)^3 = (13^2\cdot239)^4$$
$$120^4 + 13^4+ (2\cdot13)^4 = 119^4 + (4\cdot13)^4$$
and this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052569/integral-solutions-to-1-times22-times3-cdotsm-timesm1-n-timesn1) just adds to the list,
$$\frac{u(u+1)(u+2)(u+3)}{8} = \frac{v(v+1)(v+2)}{6} = \frac{w(w+1)}{2} = \frac{119\times120}2=7140$$ 
with $u=2\times\color{blue}7,\;v=2\times\color{blue}{17},\; w= \color{blue}{7\times17} =119$ such that $7140$ is the *largest* number that is both triangular and tetrahedral. (And is $3\times$ the [pentatope number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatope_number) $2380$).

> Q: Any other non-trivial Diophantine relations involving $2$nd and higher powers that $a,b,c,d,p$ satisfies?

Comment: Incidentally, in the context of _Waring's Problem_, the number $p=239$ is unique in that it needs the ***maximum*** number of nine 3rd powers and nineteen 4th powers in its representation.

Comment: Please define "non-trivial Diophantine relation". Does $2\cdot119\cdot120+1=13^4$ qualify? Do you allow combining two relations to get other ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another relation is:

$$(2\cdot2)^4-2^4-239=1$$

This implies:

$$239\cdot13^4 + 13^4 + (2\cdot13)^4 = (2\cdot2\cdot13)^4$$

which, using the first two relations on your list, gives:

$$(120^2-119^2)(120^2+119^2)+13^4+(2\cdot13)^4=(2\cdot2\cdot13)^4$$

which is equivalent to the last relation on your list.