# Find all integer solutions of the equation: $m^3-m=3n(n+1)$

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $m$ and $n$ such that
          $$m^3-m=3n(n+1)$$

Comment: $m^3-m$ is divisible by $3, \forall m\geq 1$, and, $3n(n+1)$ is also divisible by $3$, could be somewhere you can go from that.

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-integer-solutions-to-m-3-m-3n-n-1

Comment: Notice that $ m^3 - m $ is the multiplication of three consecutive numbers: $ m^3 - m = (m-1) m (m+1) $. Any triplet of consecutive numbers will always be a multiple of 3.

Comment: This is ${m+1\choose3}={n+1\choose2}$ which I suspect has been discussed here (or maybe at mathoverflow) beofre.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, 679770?

Comment: Are you still here, 679770?

Answer (score 1):

Numbers that are both triangular and tetrahedral are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A027568 and they are $0, 1, 10, 120, 1540, 7140$. $m=4,n=4$ corresponds to $10$, $m=9,n=15$ gives $120$, the others, see below. There are references and links at the OEIS page.

$$1540={22\choose3}={56\choose2}$$

$$7140={36\choose3}={120\choose2}$$

In case the connection to the original question is not clear, ${m+1\choose3}={n+1\choose2}$ is $(m+1)m(m-1)/6=n(n+1)/2$, which is $m^3-m=3n(n+1)$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214853/how-often-can-a-number-occur-in-pascals-triangle and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052569/integral-solutions-to-1-times22-times3-cdotsm-timesm1-n-timesn1

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294675/when-do-different-binomial-coefficients-coincide and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85442/are-there-surprisingly-identical-binomial-coefficients